# Imagen no responde a width

Tags: html, css, web

estoy haciendo una pagina web y entre en la parte del diseño, estoy siguiendo varios tutoriales, bueno, el punto, en mi pagina se muestran distintas imagenes que yo puse en html, pero al querer modificar su width desde el css quedan exactamente igual. 
Este es mi codigo

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700|Pacifico');
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    
}
/*-----------Estilos base*------------*/
img {
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    max-width: 100%;
    
}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6{
    margin: 0;
}
.container {
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
}
.container--flex {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}
.column {
    width: 100px;
}
/*-----------Estilos header------------*/
.main-header {
    width: 100px;
}
.logo{
    font-stretch: 1.8em;
    color: #DE423A;
    padding: 10px;
    font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;
    font-weight: 100;
    
}
.main-header__contactInfo__phone {
    background: #DE423A;
    color: white;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px;
}
.main-header__contactInfo__adress{
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0;
}
.main-header [class*="icon-"]:before {
    position: relative;
    top: 2px;
    right: 5px;
}
/*-----------Estilos header------------*/

.main-nav{
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2000;
    paddi: 10px;
}
.icon-menu {
    disp: block;
    color: white;
}
.menu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 60px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.85);
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: height.3s linear;
    
    
}
.menu__link {
    display: block;
    padding: 15px;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.menu__link:hover {
    background: #DE423A;
    
}
.menu__link--select {
    bakcground: #DE423A;  
}
.mostrar {
    height: 196px;
}
/*-----------Estilos banner------------*/
.banner {
    margin-top: -55px;
    position: relative;
}
.banner:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    z-index: 0;
    top: 0;
}
.banner__img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    object-fit: cover;
}
.banner__content {
    width: 90;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1500;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-weight: bold;
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<meta chars="UTF-8">
<title>Dissoftec</title>
    <meta name="Viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=yes, initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=3.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos.css">
   <link href="https://file.myfontastic.com/k8MQSN7TxA36UVcG7ZhvKQ/icons.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <header class="main-header">
    <div class="container container--flex">
        <div class="logo-container column--50">
        <h1 class="logo">Dissoftec</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="main-header__contactInfo column column--50">
        <p class="main-header__contactInfo__phone">
        <span class="icon-phone">Numero: (81) 1885 2578</span>
        </p>
        <p class="main-header__contactInfo__adress">
            <span class="icon-location"> Ubicacion: Tolteca 7344 Unidad Modelo </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        
    </header>
    <nav class="main-nav">
        <div class="container container--flex"></div>
        <span class="icon-menu" id="icon-menu"></span>
        <ul class="menu" id="menu">
            <li class="menu__item"><a href="" class="menu__link">Inicio</a></li>
            <li class="menu__item"><a href="" class="menu__link">Nostros</a></li>
            <li class="menu__item"><a href="" class="menu__link">Galería</a></li>
            <li class="menu__item"><a href="" class="menu__link">Contacto</a></li>
            <li class="menu__item"><a href="" class="menu__link">Registrar Datos</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <section class="banner">
    <img src="Imagenes/banner.jpg" alt="" class="banner__img">
    <div class="banner__context">Inovacion en hardware y software</div>
    </section>
    <main class="main">
        <section class="group group--color">
        <div class="container">
            <h2 class="main__title">Bienvenido a Dissoftec</h2>
            <p class="main__txt">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad aperiam porro veritatis quo libero quisquam temporibus illo quasi, fugiat recusandae, deleniti, hic architecto ipsa? Eos voluptates unde a cumque ullam.</p>
            
        </div>
         </section>
         <section class="group main__about__description">
               <div class="container container--flex">
                  <div class="column column--50">
                  <img src="Imagenes/software.jpg" alt="">
                   </div>
                   <div class="column column--50">
                       <h3 class="column__title">Expertos en tecnologia</h3>
                       <p class="column__txt">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum, ea quasi! Expedita consequatur at ad sunt, ipsa culpa quod, placeat laborum non, ipsum sequi. Laboriosam aliquam non id labore optio!</p>
                       <a href="" class="btn btn--contact">Contact</a>
                   </div>
                   
               </div>
             
         </section>
         <section class="group today-special">
             <h2 class="today-sepcial__title">Especialidades</h2>
             <div class="container container__flex">
                 <div class="column column--50-25">
                     <img src="Imagenes/columna1.jpg" alt="" class="today-special__img">
                     <div class="today-special__title">Inovacion</div>
                 </div>
                 <div class="column column--50-25">
                     <img src="Imagenes/columna2.jpg" alt="" class="today-special__img">
                     <div class="today-special__title">Inovacio1</div>
                 </div>
                 <div class="column column--50-25">
                     <img src="Imagenes/columna3.jpg" alt="" class="today-special__img">
                     <div class="today-special__title">Inovacion2</div>
                 </div>
                 <div class="column column--50-25">
                     <img src="Imagenes/columna4.jpg" alt="" class="today-special__img">
                     <div class="today-special__title">Inovacion3</div>
                 </div>
             </div>
         </section>
         
    </main>
<footer class="main-footer">
               <div class="container container--flex">
               <div class="column column--33">
               <h2 class="column__title">Por que visitarnos?</h2>
               <p class="column__txt">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A porro non reprehenderit laborum at quam voluptatum animi, ratione? Voluptatibus fugiat velit quibusdam earum dolorem ab blanditiis perspiciatis facilis possimus doloribus.</p>
               </div>
               <div class="column column--33">
               <h2 class="column__title">Contactanos</h2>
               <p class="column__txt">Tolteca 7344</p>
               <p class="column__txt">(81)1398-3197 </p>
               <p class="column__txt">dissoftec@gmail.com</p>
               </div>
               </div>
               <p class="copy">© 2019 Dissoftec | Todos los derechos reservados </p>
    </div>
             
         </footer>
         <script src="js/menu.js"></script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

> Otro problema que tengo es que al intentar subirlo a inernet, no se sube como deberia, le falta todo lo que le modifique desde el css

Comment: Hola Jesús, lee [ask] y sobre cómo crear un [mcve] y edita tu pregunta para reducirla a un ejemplo mínimo. Ahora mismo estás compartiendo cientos de líneas de código, con varias imágenes en ellas, y no queda claro cuál es la imagen/imágenes con la que tienes problemas, ni cómo quieres que se vea o cómo se ve mal ahora.

Comment: Te recomiendo a cada imagen le des una clase. Si defines valores en `css` directamente en la etiqueta `img`, tendras problemas en el fururo. Bootstrap trabaja muy bien ese tema, te lo recomiendo. Por otro lado en caso de que no se ejecuten dichas modificaciones puedes usar `!important`; `width: 100px !important;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puede que el max-width:100%; que tienes en el selector img sea el problema, me parece que tienes las imágenes dentro de un contenedor con la clase column, estos contenedores tiene un ancho fijo de 100px, por consecuencia lo máximo que las imágenes pueden crecer es 100px.

```
img {
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    max-width: 100%;
}

.column {
    width: 100px;
}
```